# Free ServerContext has failed because the Wait Timeout Interval has elapsed

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

ArcGIS Server 10 SP4 logs below entry in log file. We  have a single map service with 100+ layers which has Maximum time client can use a service is 600 seconds (10 min).
I am really surpised when some of requests failed with below message. I could not understand (or believe) which request to map server is taking more than 10 min. Can some one throw some light on this? I read all ESRI documentation and forums.

A request to obtain a free ServerContext has failed because the Wait Timeout Interval has elapsed.

Answer (score 2):

The "maximum time a client can use a service" setting doesn't relate to the error you're getting.  You want to change the setting "The maximum time a client will wait to get a service:" which is default to 60 seconds.  You could also make sure that your service can connect to your underlying data- sometimes the timeout is related to the time it takes for that connection.

The "maximum time a client can use a service" setting relates to how long a client can hold on to an instance before releasing it.  You'd want to set it longer if your client needs to do major processing, like edit data in the map service - and shorter if your client is just drawing data.

Comment: More importantly, increase the maximum number of service instances (if you have enough system resources) so that clients do not need to go through the wait period at all.

Comment: Also realize that the web server itself, eg IIS, will have a timeout on requests. If I remember right, this is normally 60 seconds. A 100+ layer service is probably failing to render in 60 seconds and resulting in a web server timeout.